# Can i use "Adsense search" in a facebook app?

Tags: google-adsense, api, facebook-application, monetize, facebook-graph

I have a Facebook app and I would like to monetize it with Adsense search, which means that people could use a "Google Adsense search box" within Facebook page.

Is it allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, there seems to be an number of grey areas.

*Quoting:*

> **Google Adsense, believe it or not is used by a huge portion** of
>   Application Developers on Facebook for many reasons, even though
>   technically Google Adsense, **isn’t designed for Social Sites** like
>   Facebook, and thus **won’t always approve**. Applications on Facebook is a
>   complex juggle to manage to make profitable, using Adverts is just one
>   of them. “Virtual Currency” is a popular choice to go in addition, but
>   that's a topic for another Article.

*and....*

> You run the risk of **having the account suspended potentially**, since
>   **Google Adsense TOS does not permit the use of IFrames** to display
>   their ads. so you take my advice at your own risk. Don’t over do it
>   with Ads on your Canvas page, I recommend one, at most 2 per page, and
>   the pages which you put the ads on within the frames, ensure their is
>   a lot of content, and not just keywords there.